# iOS - remove UIImageView from MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

My `ViewController` has a `navigationBar` with Promt and on top of it I've added a custom image:

```
- (void)changeNavBar
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"logo_home.png"];
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeLeft;

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo_home.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 70);

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar insertSubview:imageView atIndex:0];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.backItem.backBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

But when user clicks "Send Email" button, I create `MFMailComposeViewController` and present it modally.

```
- (IBAction)emailPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSString *emailTitle = event.title;
    NSString *messageBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", event.title, event.concertUrl.absoluteString];

    MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

    mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    NSLog(@"subviews: %d", mc.navigationBar.subviews.count);

    [mc setSubject:emailTitle];
    [mc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:NO];

    // Present mail view controller on screen
    [self presentModalViewController:mc animated:YES];
}
```

`MFMailComposeViewController`'s navigation bar autoresizes to normal navigationBar without prompt, but my custom image from previous VC doesn't disappear. How can I remove it and set standard Black style to my navigationBar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used UIAppearance proxy to set background image which will have effect on every navigation bar in app.

Change

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo_home.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

with

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo_home.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```